# Spectral Measures: Invertibility

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is only Q&A!*

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a spectral measure:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Regard the domain:
$$\int|f(\lambda)|^2\mathrm{d}\|E(\lambda)\varphi\|^2<\infty$$

And the calculus:
$$\langle f(E)\varphi,\chi\rangle=\int_\mathbb{C} f(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\langle E(\lambda)\varphi,\chi\rangle$$

Then equivalence holds:
$$\mathcal{N}f(E)=(0)\iff E\{f=0\}=0$$

Especially one has:
$$f(E)^{-1}=f^{-1}(E)$$

How to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the calculus:
$$f(E)E\{f=0\}=(f1_{\{f=0\}})(E)=0$$

Thus one has:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{R}E\{f=0\}\implies f(E)\varphi=0$$

Conversely regard:
$$f^{-1}(\lambda):=\frac{1}{f(\lambda)}\quad(E(\lambda)\neq0)$$

By the calculus:
$$f^{-1}(E)f(E)\subseteq(f^{-1}f)(E)=1(E)=1$$

But the domains agree:
$$\mathcal{D}f^{-1}(E)f(E)=\mathcal{D}(f^{-1}f)(E)\cap\mathcal{D}f(E)=\mathcal{H}\cap\mathcal{D}f(E)=\mathcal{D}f(E)$$

So for the operator:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}f(E):\quad f^{-1}(E)f(E)\varphi=\varphi$$

Hence one obtains:
$$f(E)^{-1}\subseteq f^{-1}(E)=(f^{-1}(E)^{-1})^{-1}\subseteq f(E)^{-1}$$

Concluding the assertion.